# Query that returns only the rows where multiple criteria in same column are met

Tags: sql, ms-access

| Client ID | Product ID | Product Description | Quantity | Contract Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 20000 | Product A | 10 | 20,000 |
| 1000 | 20001 | Product B | 1 | 150 |
| 1000 | 20002 | Product C | 25 | 5,000 |
| 1000 | 20003 | Product D | 4 | 200 |
| 1002 | 20000 | Product A | 20 | 40,000 |
| 1005 | 20003 | Product D | 6 | 300 |
| 1010 | 20000 | Product A | 70 | 140,000 |
| 1010 | 20001 | Product B | 1 | 150 |
| 1010 | 20002 | Product C | 10 | 2,000 |

I'm struggling with what should be a relatively straightforward query but this has bested me and my attempts to find the answer on my own. Hoping someone can help.

I have data organized similar to above and what I'd like to do is run a query that returns only the Client IDs that match a specific basket of product id's and sum the quantity and contract value for those product id's.

For example, a query to return every client ID that has Product A and Product B should return something like this:

| Client ID | Quantity | Contract Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 11 | 20,150 |
| 1010 | 71 | 140,150 |

I'm working with MS Access as it's what I have available on this PC :)

Various query permutations were tried...the below query returns empty but the data suggest it shouldn't

```
SELECT 
    Inventory.[ClientID], 
    SUM(Inventory.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity, 
    SUM(Inventory.[Contract Value]) AS [SumOfContract Value]
FROM 
    Inventory
GROUP BY 
    Inventory.[ClientID], Inventory.[Product ID]
HAVING 
    (((Inventory.[Product ID]) = 20000 AND 
      (Inventory.[Product ID]) = 20001));
```

Comment: What should be the expected data? Please post that as well.

Comment: First of all, `HAVING` is only meant to be applied to **aggregated** columns; if you have columns without aggregation, use `WHERE` instead (before the `GROUP BY` clause). Second - right now, your condition requires a row to have a `Product ID` of 20000 **and** 20001 **at the same time** - none of your rows will have that, obviously.

Comment: Hi, the expected data is above, see the table just above the query.

Comment: @user21323549 - I have added the answer below, please look at at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sixrcZuc4AJkbfHm3yHg3p/1

```
SELECT client_id, SUM(quantity),SUM(contract_value)
FROM products
WHERE product_description IN ('Product A', 'Product B')
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_description) = 2;
```

Comment: Hi Pranav, thank you so much this works well. There's a handful of "false positive" cases where the same product A is repeated in the data so it is being picked up by the select but there's few enough that I can manually verify. Thank you very much!